# How can I compare an ntp server's time to my server's time?

Tags: time, ntp, ntpd

I have ntpd running on a box. I want to see how the time on the box compares to the time retrieved from ntp.ubuntu.com. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I take it you just want to see the time there and not actually change your computer's time to match it?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ntpq -p ntp.ubuntu.com`

From `man ntpq`:

```
...
-p     Print  a list of the peers known to the server as well as a summary of their state. This is equivalent to the peers interactive command.
...
```

Edit:  The host is timing out right now.  `ntpq -p pool.ntp.org` will return a valid result.

Comment: ntpdate is deprecated so it's best to get in habit of using ntpq instead. However I still use ntpdate all the time myself, old habits die hard.

Comment: @Phil Hollenback : ntpdate may be "deprecated", but it works. ntpq -p often does not. Possibly because ISPs are blocking it? Or because of the server configuration?

Comment: @mivk *"Possibly because ISPs are blocking it"* This makes no sense. It's all the same NTP protocol.

Comment: @mivk @Jonathon actually, `ntpq  -p` is not asking for time, it's asking for a list of peers and other vars. If the server has a `noquery` restriction it will timeout.

Comment: `ntpq -p pool.ntp.org` times out from two of my machines, while there is no such problem with `ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org`. As said by GnP, `ntpq -p` does not do what the user expects. This incorrect answer should probably be removed. Moreover [`ntpq` cannot be installed under Debian without the associated ntp daemon](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=422347)!

Comment: `ntpq` is not an equivalent replacement for `ntpdate -q` - `sntp` is. While ntpq can return the same information as ntpdate (and much more) it uses a completely different protocol, and thus won't always be accessible (especially if the server software isn't ntpd). `sntp` (like `ntpdate` before it) use the ntp protocol, and will work with any ntp server.

Answer (score 38):

You can use [**ntpdate**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ntpdate) to query a time server

`ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can answer this question too http://serverfault.com/questions/220836/why-is-ntpd-not-updating-the-time-on-my-server

Comment: This worked for a mint box.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the command `ntpq -c "rv 0 clock" ntp.ubuntu.com` will return the time of the server in standard format : this is the result from *ca.pool.ntp.org* :

```
clock=d1b5aa9c.b8f9697a  Wed, Jun 29 2011  9:43:56.722
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options for querying an ntp server now that [ntpdate is deprecated](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate). Which is preferred is often simply a matter of which is already installed (or easy to install) on your OS:

## sntp

sntp is a tool from the ntp project, and is their recommended tool for querying remote servers:

```
$ sntp -K/dev/null ntp.ubuntu.com
2021-10-12 16:01:48.425034 (+0700) -0.175372 +/- 0.128998 secs
```

The `-K/dev/null` is optional, and disables persisting information about the requests to a file. Normal users typically won't have access to this file, so without that option it will print some errors but will otherwise work.

## chronyd

chronyd is an alternative ntp implementation and the default time server in recent RHEL and Ubuntu distributions.

```
$ chronyd -Q "server ntp.ubunutu.com iburst"
2021-10-27T21:55:49Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2021-10-27T21:55:49Z Disabled control of system clock
2021-10-27T21:55:53Z System clock wrong by -0.233053 seconds (ignored)
2021-10-27T21:55:53Z chronyd exiting
```

The `-Q` tells it to query the server and print results without setting the time (capital is important - lowercase will set the time!). By default it will query the servers configured in it's config file, but you can also give a [config line](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/4.1/chrony.conf.html#_time_sources) as done above. `server` is used to specify a single NTP server to query, but `pool` and `refclock` could also be used. `iburst` configures it get an initial result more quickly.