# Why is ntpd not updating the time on my server?

Tags: ubuntu, time, ntp, ntpd, openntpd

I have ntpd running on my server. It's all the default settings, except I commented out its ability to be a server to other machines:

```
# restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery                                                                    
# restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery   
restrict default ignore
```

If I run `ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com`, I'm told that my machine's clock is off by 7 seconds.

What's going on? How can I diagnose what's happening, is there a log I can turn on?

**more info #1**

```
# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 91.189.94.4     193.79.237.14    2 u   30   64    7  108.518   -0.136   0.361
```

**more info #2**

Here's what this looked like when I asked the question:

```
# ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com
server 91.189.94.4, stratum 2, offset 7.191308, delay 0.13310
10 Jan 20:38:09 ntpdate[31055]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset 7.191308 sec
```

And here's what it looks like now, after restarting ntpd a couple times (I'm assuming that's what fixed it):

```
# ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com
server 91.189.94.4, stratum 2, offset 0.000112, delay 0.13164
10 Jan 20:47:03 ntpdate[31419]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.000112 sec
```

**more info #3**

I uninstalled ntp and installed openntpd and ran `/usr/sbin/ntpd -d`, and I'm seeing output like this:

```
reply from 64.73.32.134: offset 6.715003 delay 0.041152, next query 30s
reply from 208.53.158.34: offset 6.700224 delay 0.036263, next query 31s
adjusting local clock by 6.734120s
reply from 72.18.205.156: offset 6.708575 delay 0.035885, next query 30s
reply from 64.73.32.134: offset 6.701463 delay 0.044199, next query 33s
```

Which to me pretty clearly indicates that I'm not able to set the time on my server (although, with regular ntp, it does seem to update sometimes...).

**more info #4**

My VPS provider says:

> The latest kernels should not lock
>   your system to our dom0's clock, to be
>   on the safe side you can set
>   xen.independent_wallclock = 1 in your
>   sysctl.conf.

Which I suppose still does not address the issue of the VPS needing a CPU available in order to do correct timing calculations.

Comment: Is that your entire config file?  If you run `ntpq -np`, what is the output?

Comment: Where's the rest of the config? There's no upstream server for your host to get time from.

Comment: no, it's not my entire config file, it's just the part i changed from the vendor config file. editing my question to show the output if `ntp -np`

Comment: Got it. It looks like ntpd was working normally. NTPd will "slew" your clock back into sync gradually. A sudden change in time can cause big problems for certain running processes so NTP works by speeding up or slowing down the length of a second to gradually make adjustments.

Comment: My server has been running for many months, so I don't think slewing is the issue -- unless every time I reboot it gets reset to the underlying hardware's clock or some such thing.

Comment: Yes, the kernel will start with the hardware clock on boot since on boot that is it's only reference. If it's been running for many months, as you say, then that isn't it. You can tell NTP to sync to your hardware clock. I'm not sure about Ubuntu but on Red Hat based systems that's in /etc/sysconfig/ntpd. You can look there or refer to your hardware's documentation.

Comment: I also don't think you understand that ntpdate is a standalone application. It doesn't have anything to do with ntpd and shouldn't be used to troubleshoot it. The reason that ntpq was suggested with the -p options to show peering. If ntpd sees your peer(s), then it should be bringing the system back into sync.  Looks like everything is good now, though.  I just hoped to provide some extra insight.  Hope this helps in the future!

Comment: I was using ntpq to check if ntp was doing its job -- IE, to see if the system clock is off or not.

Comment: The `-b` option should be used with ntpd to set the clock on boot without slowly slewing the clock. This option is commonly used on devices that don't have a battery backed RTC. Also, you really should have several sources for time, not just rely on a single server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright folks, in the time since asking this question, I've reinstalled ntp with the default vendor (Ubuntu 10.0.4) config and let it run for a few days. As of this writing, `ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com` shows that my time is accurate to within 0.000216 seconds. So, the problems I was having must have been with my customized config (where I was trying to make it impossible for external hosts to query my server, which I'm already doing with my firewall so I'm not too worried about). Here is the Ubuntu 10.0.4 ntp.conf in its entirety, with comments removed:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server ntp.ubuntu.com

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

I welcome feedback on how this config might be improved.

I also made a ticket with my VPS provider asking them for a detailed recommendation on the best thing to do. I pointed them to this thread, and some other documentation indicating that maybe the CPU allocation would cause a timing problem. Here is what they said:

> The latest kernels should not lock
>   your system to our dom0's clock, to be
>   on the safe side you can set
>   xen.independent_wallclock = 1 in your
>   sysctl.conf. This will make sure the
>   server instance isn't following the
>   clock on the host server.

and:

> I think you may be mis-understanding
>   the exact degree to which this issue
>   affects NTP clients in a virtualized
>   environment.  In my experience on a
>   virtualized system on a Xen host (such
>   as our setup at Rackspace Cloud) the
>   inaccuracy inherited by not having a
>   dedicated system clock to process the
>   interrupts amounts to fractions of a
>   second, even on highly loaded systems.
>   This slight inaccuracy is easily
>   managed by NTP even if it is only set
>   to update the servers time once per
>   day (or even less frequent than that).

Answer (score 12):

You can enable logging in ntpd by adding this to ntp.conf:

```
logfile /var/log/ntpd.log
```

Source: [ntp manual](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/miscopt.html#logconfig)

If you turn off ntpd, can you update the clock by command line? If you run the ntpdate command and receive an error like so:

```
# ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
10 Jan 23:47:57 ntpdate[26284]: Can't adjust the time of day: Operation not permitted
```

This means that you are probably on a VPS, and in that case you can not modify the system clock - this can only be done on the host machine.

Comment: ntpdate is happy to do its thing -- But I wonder if when my server reboots the clock gets reset to the hardware's clock or some such thing?

Comment: After you use ntpdate to set the clock, use 'hwclock --systohc' to sync "running" time to your hardware clock. It is supposed to sync on a reboot but if your machine crashes (or otherwise had a problem doing a proper shutdown) it could not sync it.

Comment: Well it's a vhost, so I don't have access to the hardware clock (at least I hope not!)

Comment: There's an emulated hardware clock just as there is emulated BIOS.

Comment: I was the admin on several VPS platforms, none of them (openvz, Xen) have access to set the clock on the system. They all had to be done at the host level. Submit a ticket with your host to indicate the time is off, they should be running ntp and have the time synchronized for you.

Comment: Is it possible that `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` succeeds, but isn't "really" working? Or does the failure of that command correspond 1-1 with my inability to set the clock in a VPS?

Comment: You might also need to use sudo...

Answer (score 4):

One of your comments says you are running on a vhost.  In this case, you are probably not going to have much success because your vhost's sense of time is going to be dependent both on the real host it is running on and by how busy overall the vhost is.

Depending on the virtualization used, the vhost may not get a steady share of interrupts in a given time period.  This will make the clock run faster, or slower, than is really happening.  Since ntp is trying to measure changes on the assumption that your clock is a fixed-rate faster or slower than the rest of the world, this speeding up and slowing down will give ntp fits and it will probably eventually just give up, with the result that `ntp -np` shows time servers that ntp has deemed unsuitable.

Your best bet if this is the case is probably a brute-force `rdate -s $server` every so often (like every six hours) to yank the clock around by its nose so that it doesn't drift excessively out of sync.  But fine-grained accuracy is probably out of reach.

Comment: My hosting provider (rackspace cloud) has told me that NTP works fine in their environment.

Comment: See my submitted/accepted answer for what my VPS provider said about the clock, and access to setting the time.

Comment: automatic rdate can set the clock backwards, which can have unexpected consequences aplenty.

Answer (score 4):

Things I've found in the past, when I used ntpd instead of openntpd:

1. You need to permit access to localhost for ntpd to start properly and actually do stuff

   ```
   restrict 127.0.0.1
   restrict ::1
   ```
2. Although you can use hostnames for server rules, opening back up holes to talk with those servers means using `restrict` which requires IP addresses, so I ended up having to use IPs for everything anyway.
3. You don't mention using `restrict` to open access back up to your servers.  That's an issue.  Try blocks such as the following:

   ```
   # ntp.xs4all.nl
   server          194.109.22.18
   restrict        194.109.22.18
   ```
4. You need multiple peers or servers for ntpd, since it tries to use majority-rules voting to deal with a bad actor.  So a minimum of 4, to still be able to have a majority when you lose one, preferably 5.
5. To lock down the default access, I could use:

   ```
   restrict default notrust nomodify
   ```

   so as to still be able to query, but I ended up using `restrict default ignore` as you do when ntpd 4.2 changed the meaning of `notrust`.  *sigh*
6. If you're not providing time-service to others, then you probably don't need the full power of regular ntpd and you should consider `openntpd` instead.  Written by the OpenBSD crew, it's a far more minimal implementation, using privilege separation and a much simpler config file.  It allegedly won't provide the highly precise time that ntpd will, but it's easily good enough for a regular server or workstation.

Comment: This is great info. I'm checking out openntpd. Question: do you concur or disagree with the other folks who claim that setting the clock on a vhost is impossible?

Comment: And perhaps you can answer this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/223511/how-often-does-openntpd-update-the-time

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying with your various `restrict` rules… do those rules affect which servers I can query for time too? I thought it only affected which nodes can ask me for time.

Comment: Here's an idea: wanna change your answer into a complete minimal ntp.conf file with comments? :-)

Comment: Setting the clock on a vhost is ill-advised, unless you're guaranteed to always be scheduled with at least one CPU, since otherwise the time perceived by the vhost does not match the time of the outside world. The dom0 should be maintaining time.  The other question's answer is good.  NTP is UDP, so you need to permit packets from the servers which you query for time.  My ntpd is stale as I moved to OpenNTPD a few years ago.

Comment: Phil P: Thanks for all your info and ideas. See my submitted and accepted answer for my resolution to this, and let me know what you think of that config.

Answer (score 4):

- If ntpd wouldn't be able to connect with the remote server, you
  wouldn't see an offset for that server.
- If ntpq would be blocked by ntpd, you would see a clear error message from ntpq.
- If some other
  service would set also the time (like vmware tools), you would see a
  jumping offset for the server (run ntpq -p every 70 seconds).

The `reach 7` in ntpq output indicated, that you let ntpd only run for around 4 minutes. 7 is 111 binary, which means the server was reached already 3 times. ntp reaches out every 64 seconds (`poll` value) and waited already 30 seconds (`when` value) since the last contact.

The `offset -0.136` indicated, that the system is already synchronized. Only ntpd hasn't marked the server as source, yet. Just give it more time and a little star will appear.

So, actually your ntpd was syncing. But ntpd doesn't usually sync in one big jump (like ntpdate), but tries to adjust the time slowly and ensures over several cycles, that the time is stable.

PS: I am aware, that the question is very old. But the issue is timeless. And all the other answers are just misleading IMHO. ntpd is even recommended by VMWare to keep the time in sync.

Comment: Great first answer, Robert. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I found my system off and puzzled why the HW clock wasn't sync'ing with the system clock on a clean shutdown. Seems there's an NTP setting in sysconfig that needs editing to make that happen.

In `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd`:

```
# Set to 'yes' to sync hw clock after successful ntpdate
SYNC_HWCLOCK=no
```

I set that to `yes`. Of course first verify that you have a solid NTP server and your system clock is reliable.

I knew that was it - my skew was 47 seconds and my HW clock was also 47 seconds off. Bingo!
My first clue was Kerberos failures seen in the logs. Kerberos and many NAS will just not work if clock skew is too great.

Have a Nice Day!

Comment: Snap .. that's RHEL/Centos relevant. Perhaps not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This was not OP’s issue, but another reason for ntpd not syncing could be that the ntp port (123) is blocked (e.g. by the company’s firewall).

A solution is to use [htpdate](https://www.vervest.org/htp/?FAQ), which has a daemon mode (`-D`).

[[credits](https://superuser.com/a/1259754/127425)]

Answer (score 0):

if you are running vhost on vmware check the following article..it shuld help you
http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Hai..

Take a look at this reference to see if it can assist in troubleshooting your issue:

[http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch24*:_The_NTP_Server](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch24_:_The_NTP_Server)

you might want to post the contents of your ntpd.conf file, the output of the debug commands like ntpq -p

And check your date/time?

And verify this also, run ntpdate and startup ntpd, is the time keeping in sync?

with best wishes