# How often does openntpd update the time?

Tags: ntp, ntpd, openntpd

Neither the openntpd nor the ntpd.conf manpage have this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time updating happens on a continuous basis. The daemon keeps track of how the time-rate of the hardware clock drifts from the time reported by the upstream sources. It polls the upstream sources based on an algorithm and can change. The actual poll-rate is a power-of-two in seconds. You can query this information through the `ntpq` command.

Different time daemons have different defaults for what it'll allow the maximum poll time to be. I've seen it go as long as a couple of *days* between polls of upstream servers, and others where it never goes past about 20 minutes. The `minpoll` and `maxpoll` values on your `server` lines in the ntpd.conf file itself will provide, if set, the exact power-of-two for that upstream server.

Upstream polling is used to determine how to modify the drift rate. It is very important for the NTP daemon to not hard-set time, instead it just increases the length of a second by a tiny amount for a while until the local time converges with the time reported by the upstream time servers.

Answer (score 4):

NTPd is always actively adjusting the time.  It works by speeding up the length of a second or slowing it down to bring the time into sync gradually.  A sudden change in time can be problematic for many services / daemons.  It's widely considered better practice to correct it this way.  If you are sure you won't be affected and need a quick sync for a clock that's way off, stop the ntpd service and use the ntpdate command.

Comment: +1 Stopping ntpd isn't necessary to use `ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org` though. The process by which it updates the clock is called slewing the clock (as Aaron described). Ntpd checks with its configured time servers on a regular basis, usually between 64 and 1024 seconds (by default) depending on the stability of the local and remote clocks.

Comment: Oh nice, the `-u` sends it out an unprivileged port which gets around the socket in use error...  Didn't know about that!